# Can't install Ubuntu because live system uses too high monitor frequency

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, graphics, xorg, monitor

I just downloaded Ubuntu 15.04 and I put it into a pendrive. When I boot the pendrive, Ubuntu logo starts to charge but after a while, the monitor turns black with the mesaje "Frequency out of range: Horizontal 95 KHz - Vertical 60 Hz", so I cant continue with the installation due to not seeing anything.

My graphics card is nVidia GTX-970. My monitor is an old ViewSonic VG2021wm that probably does not support more than 60Hz or even less.

**How can I configure the Ubuntu installer to decrease the used monitor frequency?**

Comment: I guess you mean "Vertical 60**Hz**"? 60 KHz screen refresh frequency would really be extreme overclocking.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Vertical is 60Hz, and Horizontal is 95KHz. My monitor is 8 years old but with older versions of Ubuntu I never had problem. Now I want to be back with Ubuntu (I'm using Win10 right now) but I have this little issue.

Comment: Since 15.04 (I think), my monitor also sometimes just shortly turns off and back on, together with that click sound old CRT monitors make when changing the resolution. But I never saw such an error. I am right that the monitor itself displays this error, not the system?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that is the monitor. It displayed the error in a little blue box in the meddle of the screen. That blue box is from the monitor's menu. The same frequency problem I had when I plug the screen to my notebook, and the notebook works perfectly. The problem is that the system shows more than 60Hz and the screen dont support more of 60Hz, but I have no idea how to deal with it in Ubuntu.

Comment: It would be good if you added the exact brand and model of your monitor, too. And I've edited your question a bit to attract the right people.

Comment: Thanks for the tittle help!
The monitor is a "ViewSonic VG2021wm", but is not a CRT :P
I was reading, and when this happens I press "CTRL+ALT+F1" and I acced to the terminal but asking me for a User and Password, but the SO is just loaded into the pendrive, so I dont know :(

Comment: Changed that. You know you may [edit] your question yourself too? And the default live user has the username `ubuntu` and a blank password.

Comment: What might maybe help: http://askubuntu.com/a/672068/367990