# Changing display settings during ubuntu 15.04 installation

Tags: system-installation, 15.04, display-resolution

I am trying to install ubuntu 15.04 as my first OS on a new PC. When i boot it from usb and select either "try ubuntu without installing" or "install ubuntu" i get the ubuntu logo for a few seconds and then an "out of range" disclaimer on my monitor. I've read that this is somehow connected to display settings being too high for the monitor but i have no idea how to change them. So my question is how to change any display settings during ubuntu installation or if there is any other way to solve the "out of range" issue?

My monitor: ASUS VS 197

My graphics card: GeForce GTX 970 JetStream

Comment: possible duplicate of [Freezing Ubuntu while installing from live usb](http://askubuntu.com/questions/670887/freezing-ubuntu-while-installing-from-live-usb)

Comment: I read the thread you linked but i dont know how to set the nomodeset parameter on my PC. I have a similar installation screen as the one linked but without all the f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 options, nothing happens when i press any f-key and there are no advanced options. How would i go about setting it to nomodeset?

Comment: Did you try to press `e` and type in nomodeset manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to boot with `nomodeset` parameter.

If you boot in UEFI mode, when you get the menu "Try Ubuntu", "Install Ubuntu", etc., press `e` and type in `nomodeset` after `splash`.

After you successfully install Ubuntu you probably will need to boot with `nomodeset` again, then install Nvidia drivers by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

Comment: I managed to install ubuntu the way you recommended. How do i set nomodeset on again, now that it automatically launches ubuntu when i turn on the PC? Or do you mean i should boot from the usb again? And in that case should i select "try ubuntu"?

Comment: No you need to press ESC or Shift to get to grub again.